# Как вернуть с сервера сообщение об ошибке с русским текстом?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть метод на сервере:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(Document model)
{
    //какая то проверка
    if()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Какой то текст");
    }
}
```

при выполнении условия в блоке `if` в ответ приходит ошибка, вот только в поле `statusText` вместо ***Какой то текст*** приходит *кракозябра*.

Подскажите как вернуть с сервера ошибку с текстом отличным от английского.

P.S.:

- на странице установлена кодировка `utf-8`;
- в заголовках ответа установлена кодировка `utf-8`
- файл с исходным кодом так же в кодировке `utf-8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кратко: никак. Эта проблема не связана с неправильно установленной кодировкой cs-файла, charset в системном шаблоне страницы или заголовком сервера: она воспроизведётся даже на пустом проекте asp.net mvc.

Дело в том, что в заголовках можно использовать только [символы ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

В [RFC 7230 раздел 3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) содержит следующее упоминание:

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data.

> Исторически, HTTP разрешает в полях контента только текст в кодировке
> ISO-8859-1, поддержка других символов определена в стандарте RFC2047
> ("MIME Часть третья: Расширения заголовка для не ASCII текста"). Но на
> практике, большинство полей содержит только символы из набора
> US-ASCII. Поэтому рекомендуется: новые заголовки ДОЛЖНЫ ограничиваться
> символами из набора US-ASCII. Получатели (браузеры и т.п.) ДОЛЖНЫ
> трактовать любые другие символы как "чёрный ящик" (opaque data - здесь
> как "бинарные данные", "obs" = "obsolete", устаревший)

При подготовке использовались материалы из следующих вопросов:

- [What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header)
- [Sending non-ASCII text in Http POST header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251824/sending-non-ascii-text-in-http-post-header)